# What is the word for raining without clouds?

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember the word to be no English. I once have seen this word on a website which I don't recall the address.

Answer (score 5):

maybe you're thinking of :

***sunshower***

[from the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunshower):

> A sunshower or sun shower is a meteorological phenomenon in which rain falls while the sun is shining.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunshower) A sunshower is usually the result of accompanying winds associated with a rain storm sometimes miles away, blowing the airborne raindrops into an area where there are no clouds. Hence, a sunshower. Sometimes a sunshower is created when a single rain cloud passes overhead, and the Sun's angle keeps the sunlight from being obstructed by overhead clouds.

Comment: Such an effect is perhaps less strange in the British Isles, with our maritime climate. (One where, it is sometimes said, you can get all four seasons in the same day!) A short summer shower often takes place in sunshine. As a child one is taught, in such circumstances, to "look for the rainbow".

Answer (score 0):

"Serein"

> "rain falling from a cloudless sky"

[Glossary of the American Meteorological Society](http://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Serein)

[Quarterly Journal of the American Meteorological Society, July 22 1889](https://rmets.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qj.4970157017)

[Monthly Weather Review, 1917](https://books.google.com/books?id=jj9OAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA13&ots=tiEqAB7Ymz&dq=meteorology%20serein&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q=serein&f=false)